aedebug debugger gets triggered for seemingly-normal process exit
Our desktop Windows app is installed on many customers' machines, and when installing, we also setup aedebug registry to run windbg and capture crash log+minidump (details below), which we collect.
This works, but sometimes we get a crash log/dump which looks like a normal process exit - no exceptions, one thread with stack ending in NtTerminateProcess() (details below).
Question: Why would such a process exit trigger the aedebug debugger?
Note: The app's main .exe is native code (written in C++), but there are many modules that are managed - some written in C++/CLI and some in C#.
Dump debugging
0:000> .exr -1
ExceptionAddress: 0000000000000000
   ExceptionCode: 80000003 (Break instruction exception)
  ExceptionFlags: 00000000
NumberParameters: 0

0:000> .ecxr
Minidump doesn't have an exception context
Unable to get exception context, HRESULT 0x80004002

0:000> ~*k

.  0  Id: 6e18.d6c Suspend: -1 Teb: 00000000`002d7000 Unfrozen
Child-SP          RetAddr           Call Site
00000000`000cfac8 00007fff`1dc4ef98 ntdll!NtTerminateProcess+0x14
00000000`000cfad0 00007fff`1bc3e3eb ntdll!RtlExitUserProcess+0xb8
00000000`000cfb00 00007fff`1444883e kernel32!ExitProcessImplementation+0xb
00000000`000cfb30 00007fff`14977580 mscoreei!RuntimeDesc::ShutdownAllActiveRuntimes+0x2fa
00000000`000cfe10 00007fff`1b886d93 mscoree!ShellShim_CorExitProcess+0x130
00000000`000cfe40 00007fff`1b8505b4 ucrtbase!try_cor_exit_process+0x367cf
00000000`000cfe70 00007fff`1b85045f ucrtbase!exit_or_terminate_process+0x3c
00000000`000cfea0 00000001`4002f8e8 ucrtbase!common_exit+0x6f
00000000`000cfef0 00007fff`1bc37374 MyApp!__scrt_common_main_seh+0x168 [D:\a\_work\1\s\src\vctools\crt\vcstartup\src\startup\exe_common.inl @ 295]
00000000`000cff30 00007fff`1dc3cc91 kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x14
00000000`000cff60 00000000`00000000 ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x21

0:000> r
rax=000000000000002c rbx=0000000000000000 rcx=ffffffffffffffff
rdx=0000000000000000 rsi=0000000000000000 rdi=0000000000000000
rip=00007fff1dc8dae4 rsp=00000000000cfac8 rbp=00000000000cfee0
 r8=0000000000000000  r9=00007fff1b7c0230 r10=0000000000000000
r11=00000000000cf750 r12=0000000000000000 r13=0000000000000001
r14=0000000000000001 r15=0000000003563440
iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na po nc
cs=0033  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00000246
ntdll!NtTerminateProcess+0x14:
00007fff`1dc8dae4 c3              ret

0:000> u ntdll!NtTerminateProcess
ntdll!NtTerminateProcess:
00007fff`1dc8dad0 4c8bd1          mov     r10,rcx
00007fff`1dc8dad3 b82c000000      mov     eax,2Ch
00007fff`1dc8dad8 f604250803fe7f01 test    byte ptr [SharedUserData+0x308 (00000000`7ffe0308)],1
00007fff`1dc8dae0 7503            jne     ntdll!NtTerminateProcess+0x15 (00007fff`1dc8dae5)
00007fff`1dc8dae2 0f05            syscall
00007fff`1dc8dae4 c3              ret    <<<<<<<<<<<<< rip points here, after the syscall
00007fff`1dc8dae5 cd2e            int     2Eh
00007fff`1dc8dae7 c3              ret


Aedebug installation details
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AeDebug]
"Auto"="1"
"UserDebuggerHotKey"=dword:00000000
"Debugger"="\"(...)\\windbg.exe\" -p %ld -e %ld -g -Q -QS -QY -QSY -WX -sins -c '$$>< \"(...)\\DebuggerCommands.txt\"'"

With DebuggerCommands.txt starting as:
.logopen /t "(...)\crash.log"
.dump -o -u -mFhutip "(...)\crash.dmp"
(more analysis commands)


I don't have a solution but it's an interesting problem. The usual route (for the JIT debugger to be triggered) would be exception -> kernel -> alert WER service -> look at AeDebug Key -> spawn "AeDebug" program. Only scenario I can think of rn is a forced system shut down (you know when you try to quit windows, but it tells you that some program are still doing something). In this case, the kernel have a specific action to force the program to quit, which may (I'm speculating here) be seen as a crash. Can you cross ref with your client about any errors in logged events (i.e event viewer)?

@Neitsa: Interesting. I did start to collected event logs recently, though not sure whether it's deployed it. Will update here if I know more about this mystery.
